# Uiautomator viewer

Tags: android-uiautomator, ui-testing

I have been working on UI tetsing lately. I worked on Espresso and UI automator. While using UI automator viewer i am able to get the hierarchy and id of the UI component when i am using Nexus tablet home screen , however whenever i am using Xperia tablet and taking device screenshot using ui automator viewer i am not able to get the UI component correctly . There is some issue as seen in below in the image . Any suitable reason why is it happening ? [image]Is it  because google Ui automator work best for google devices?

This above uiautomator viewer screenshot is for google nexus where i am clearly getting the app button id when i move my cursor over it.[image]
This one is for xperia tablet where you can see it is pointing to empty place and still giving some heirarchical view(Image button) and id(seems as some coordinate mismatch).

Comment: Its may be because of the orientation issue. Try changing  the orientation to portrait and then take the view hierarchy

Comment: hi @Naga2Raja i did that before . but still the same issue persist

Comment: I too had faced these kind of issue. But my objective is to know the details of some elements which I preferably get from the UI Automator (even if its not showing the right elements).  Try using "monitor", that may fit your needs

Comment: It probably has something to do with how Xperia layouts its elements. I'd say this is a problem with how the tablet OS is used and not with the UIAutomatorViewer